# GNU make: variable for command line arguments

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How to pass the entire command line (including goals, link lines, make options etc) from top level make to recursive make:

```
targets : prerequisites
    $(MAKE) $(this should  expand to top level command line) additional_args
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is using a combination of `$(MAKE)`, which contains the exact filename make was invoked with, `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`, which contains the goals you specified on the command line, and `$(MAKEFLAGS)`, which contains any variable definitions and (a subset of) the switches specified on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

The `$(MAKE)` macro is special and expands to include some relevant options. See the section [How the MAKE variable works](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) in the Make documentation for more details. However, this doesn't include the complete line including goals etc, and I'm not sure that is possible.

Usually I try to avoid using Make recursively, there's a good article about that here: [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/).